# Importing In Python

Tags: python, import

Is it possible to import modules based on location?

(eg. do all modules i import have to be in /usr/lib64/python2.5/ or a similar dir?)

I'd like to import a module that's local to the current script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can extend the path at runtime like this:

```
sys.path.extend(map(os.path.abspath, ['other1/', 'other2/', 'yourlib/']))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) to add or remove locations that python will search whenever you attempt an import.

Answer (score 3):

- python will import from the current directory by default.
- **sys.path** is the variable that controls where python searches for imports.

Answer (score 0):

You can import module that are in the same path the module you are importing to. For example:

Directory contains:  `mod1.py, mod2.py`

```
mod2.py
--------
import mod1
```

Or you can add any directory to your PYTHON_PATH variable:

```
import sys
sys.path.extend('/user/some/other/directory')
import mod1
```

Answer (score 0):

It searches in ./lib by default.

Answer (score 0):

For low-level control over the import process, the [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) module lets you import modules from arbitrary open files under arbitrary names.

For example, if this is `foo.py`:

```
def x():
    print 'hello, world'
```

Then this code:

```
import imp

with open('foo.py', 'r') as module_file:
    imp.load_module('module_name', module_file, '', ('', 'r', imp.PY_SOURCE))

import module_name

module_name.x()
```

prints "hello, world".

Answer (score 0):

### Use **init**.py

The only problem with doing dynamic modification of sys.path is that you need to repeat it in every script and hard-code the pathnames. That gets messy and non DRY if you have even two or three files.

Instead, if your file structure looks like this:

```
~/foo/__init__.py
~/foo/foo.py
~/foo/bar/__init__.py
~/foo/bar/baz.py
```

Here the **init**.py's are blank files created with touch, while foo.py and baz.py are actual python scripts. Then you can do something like this:

```
import sys
try:
    from foo import foo
    from foo.bar import baz
except ImportError:
    "%s is not in %s. Add to your PYTHONPATH in ~/.bashrc" % \
    (os.path.expanduser("~/foo"),sys.path)
```

Structuring your stuff as a package from the beginning is a *little* more work but makes it much easier to scale the project later and to see where imports are coming from. Moreover, if you move stuff around, you can use a single symlink rather than doing a find/replace through your codebase. E.g. if you moved '~/foo' to '~/downloads/foo', just do this:

```
cd ~
ln -s ~/downloads/foo foo
```

And all your imports will still work.